# Python. База данных студентов (с использовавнием текстовика)

Tags: python, база-данных, файлы

Нужна помощь с выводом данных из текстового файла на экран. Можно добавить несколько элементов, но выводит на экран программа только 1 элемент.

```
import pickle
import sys

def add_stud(FILENAME, users):
    with open(FILENAME, "ab") as file:
        pickle.dump(users, file)

def print_stud(FILENAME):
    i = 1
    with open(FILENAME, "rb") as file:
        users_from_file = pickle.load(file)
        for user in users_from_file:
            print('[', i, '] - ', "Имя:", user[0], "\tФамилия:", user[1], "\tГод рождения:", user[2])
            i += 1

FILENAME = "users.dat"

while True:
    print(" [1] - Добавить запись о студенте")
    print(" [2] - Удалить запись о студенте")
    print(" [3] - Вывести на экран записи о студентах")
    print(" [4] - Отсортировать записи по возрасту")
    print(" [5] - Средний возраст студентов")
    print(" [6] - Выход из программы")
    do = input("Укажите номер действия: ")

    if do == "1":
        users = [
        [input('Имя - '), input('Фамилия - ') ,int(input('Год рождения - '))]
        ]
        '''users = {
            0: input('Имя - '),
            1: input('Фамилия - '),
            2: int(input('Год рождения - '))
        }'''
        add_stud(FILENAME, users)
        print('Запись добавлена\n')

    elif do == "2":
        pass

    elif do == "3":
        print_stud(FILENAME)

    elif do == "4":
        pass

    elif do == "5":
        pass

    elif do == "6":
        sys.exit()

    else:
        print("\nПопробуй еще раз.\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

pickle.load(file) - считывает один объект, а не все.
Поэтому - лучше записывать в csv - file и читать в цикле for.
Либо - если хотите использовать модуль pickle - записывать в отдельный файл количество записанных студентов для цикла чтения pickle.load(file) по счетчику.

Answer (score 1):

Функция `add_stud()` записывает список с только одним студентом у вас. `pickle.load()` читает ровно одну иерархию объекта из файла. Всё что дальше в файле идёт игнорируется.

В принципе можно пока конец файла не встретится, продолжать читать, но если вы хотите использовать pickle как формат сериализации, то следует сразу целиком все записи писать в виде одного списка (используйте "wb" вместо  "ab").

Для базы данных, встроенной в процесс, может лучше подойти [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).